# Reset fmax.accumulate when cross array (Python Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, accumulate

I'm trying to get cumulative max of array1 until it reach the levels of array2, then it will restart accumulation from those points.
So:      (RsiMa and DeltaFastAtrRsi are arrays)

```
long = (RsiMa - DeltaFastAtrRsi)   
longband = np.fmax.accumulate(long)
```

but at the points where `longband >= RsiMa`:

```
longband = long
```

and then, max accumulation will restart from this point.

[image]

```
UPPER LINE = RsiMa (array2)
LOWER LINE = longband (array1)
```

I NEED TO DO THIS WITHOUT LOOPS!!! (NUMPY)

EDIT EXAMPLE:

```
                          0   1   2   3   4   5   6
RsiMa                     4   4   4   3   5   2   1
long                      1   2   3   2   4   1  0.5   
np.fmax.accumulate(long)  1   2   3   3   4   4   4

expected output           1   2   3   2   4   1  0.5
                                      ^       ^   ^
```

In the highlighted points (2, 1, 0.5) `expected output` was `>= RsiMa`, so the output is equal to the `long` value, and accumulation will restart from those points.

Comment: Please provide some context and [mre]. Remember that *you* may have been banging your head against the wall for hours about this, but we have zero clue what you're talking about. We'll need some introduction to what you're working with here.

Comment: @deceze edited with example <3

Comment: @deceze ...and context...